# Snowflake Need to get the closes date/data with multiple records on a key

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to join two tables where I need to get the rent for the closest date. I need to do a left join from t1 and get all the values from t2

```sql
with t1 as (
 
    select '02/26/2024' as reporting_week, '1361164' as propertyid
    union 
    select '02/19/2024' as reporting_week, '1361164' as propertyid
    union 
    select '02/11/2024' as reporting_week, '1361164' as propertyid
    union 
    select '02/09/2024' as reporting_week, '1361164' as propertyid
    union 
    select '02/09/2024' as reporting_week, '1369999' as propertyid
),
t1 as (
select '02/25/2024' as date, '1361164' as id, 999 as rent
union 
select '02/19/2024' as date, '1361164' as id, 888 as rent
union 
select '02/10/2024' as date, '1361164' as id, 777 as rent
)
```

I need to get the closest date rent from t1
desired output should be:

| propertyid | reporting_week | rent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1361164 | '02/26/2024' | 999 |
| 1361164 | '02/19/2024' | 888 |
| 1361164 | '02/11/2024' | 777 |
| 1361164 | '02/09/2024' | 777 |
| 1369999 | '02/09/2024' | 0.00 |

has context menu.

Here is what I tried:

```sql
with date_calc as( 
    select t1.pid, 
           t1.date, 
           max(t2a.date) as t2a_date, 
           max(t2b.date) as t2b_date 
    from t1 
    left join t2 t2a 
           on t2a.id = t1.pid 
          and t2a.date <= t1.date 
    left join t2 t2b 
           on t2b.id = t1.pid 
    group by t1.pid, t1.date ) 
select dc.pid, 
       dc.date, 
       t2.rent 
from date_calc dc 
join t2 on t2.id=dc.pid 
       and t2.date = coalesce(t2a_date, t2b_date);
```

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what issues are you facing?

Comment: @NickW,
Sorry, I  forgot to copy my sql as I was still working on it,
Here is what I tried.



date_calc as( 
    select 
        t1.pid,
        t1.date,
        max(t2a.date) as t2a_date,
        max(t2b.date) as t2b_date
    from t1
    left join t2 t2a
        on t2a.id = t1.pid
        and t2a.date <= t1.date
    left join t2 t2b
        on t2b.id = t1.pid
    group by t1.pid, t1.date
)
 
select 
    dc.pid,
    dc.date,
    t2.rent
from date_calc dc
join t2
    on t2.id=dc.pid
    and t2.date = coalesce(t2a_date, t2b_date);

Comment: Hi - please update your question rather than add additional information in a comment. Then someone can read the question and see all the information in one place - rather than having to work through comments, try and work out if the information is still relevant, etc.

Comment: Sure. Will update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in luck with a new function in Snowflake that is in Public Preview at the moment.  It's called `ASOF JOIN` and you can find the documentation to it here (currently):

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/asof-join

However, your requirements need to be defined a bit better in order to use it correctly.  For example, what is considered a tie-breaker in "closest" if 2 dates are equally distant?  Do you prefer to take the previous rent date over the later rent date?

The `ASOF JOIN` allows you to choose a record that is the closest before OR the closest after, but you can do something like this in order to make sure that records have a value if there is an absence of a record in one way or the other.

```sql
with t1(reporting_week,propertyid) as (
    select * from (values 
    ('02/26/2024', '1361164'),
    ('02/19/2024', '1361164'),
    ('02/11/2024', '1361164'),
    ('02/09/2024', '1361164'),
    ('02/09/2024', '1369999'))
),
t2(date,id,rent) as (
    select * from (values 
    ('02/25/2024', '1361164', 999),
    ('02/19/2024', '1361164', 888),
    ('02/10/2024', '1361164', 777))
)
select t1.propertyid, t1.reporting_week, coalesce(t2.rent,t3.rent) as rent
from t1
asof join t2
     match_condition (t1.reporting_week::date >= t2.date::date)
  on t1.propertyid = t2.id
asof join t2 t3
     match_condition (t1.reporting_week::date <= t3.date::date)
  on t1.propertyid = t3.id
order by t1.reporting_week desc
;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the query. This is close to what I am looking for. Only think that I would expect the last record also should have a value of 777. I will reference this and  incorporate changes to mine. Thanks you very much !!

Comment: @Raj For that line, you specified `0.0` in your expected result and in your sample data, you didn't list any `rent` entries for property `1369999`. Why do you expect `777`?

Comment: You are right @Zegarek.

Comment: @Zegarek Thank you for updating my CTEs.  I wanted to use the OP's code for those directly, but I 100% agree that using values is far more efficient.